# Update to current branch's head in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, tortoisehg-2.0

How am I supposed to update current branch to head in TortoiseHg 2.x?

In console I just perform `hg up`, but in tortoisehg I need to find current revision, look its name, switch to the current branch in the "filter toolbar" and find out *manually* the current branch's head. It is very odd, imho.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right Click -> Tortoise HG -> Update -> Update to: Choose default / tip /branchname

Or in Workbench, right click on Tip and select Update. Or you can just right click, Update and select update to branchname / tip without worrying about the revision you are looking at.

Comment: The issue is that I need manually find the current branch's head ;-) But yes, context menu `thg -> Update` solves the issue a little. But it would be nice if it were a solution in workbench

Comment: @manojlds: yes, and I still cannot get how to perform the command like `hg up` without looking up of current branch name and its head. Did I miss something?

Comment: @zerkms In workbench, just rightclick, select Update, select Update to. In the dropdown you have tip and branchname. Select them and you update to branch head / tip.

Comment: @manojlds: in that window we still don't have current branch name, so we have no idea what branch to update to, until we look up to the current revision and see its branch name.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: how? I should always keep it in mind? Oh, it is displayed in the topmost `N+` virtual commit. Then yes, probably it is a solution.